# Adding users to my Cognito Forms account

Tags: cognito-forms

Creating a form is simple enough, as is getting it to show up on my WordPress site. However, I am the webmaster for an organization that will eventually have multiple forms. The person responsible for acting on the entries made in the form will never be me, and if they choose to be notified by email, that should go to them, not to me.

How do I create additional users connected to my Cognito Forms account and give them access to entries for their specific forms?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. Currently we don’t allow for additional users within a single Cognito account. However, this is a feature we are actively working on and plan to add in an upcoming release, and you can follow its progress on our idea board(No longer public). In the interim, you can set each specific form to send its entry notifications to one or more email address. This is under the Form Settings menu, and you can check the box to include entry details as well. This would allow other people in your organization to review the entries without having to log in. Hopefully this is a good workaround for your organization until we add multi-user support, but if there are additional features you’d like to see, you can use our [request form](https://www.cognitoforms.com/featurerequest).

Answer (score 0):

You now have the ability to add additional users to an organization in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) and limit permissions on a form by form basis, including Administrator, Editor and Reviewer permissions.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/152/account--organizations/user-management